# Prevent glossary entries from separating title and description at page breaks

Tags: page-breaking, glossaries

I have modified the `glossaries` `indexgroup` style to match my needs, which includes a few line breaks. However, these result in entries being split at page breaks. How can I get around this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nopostdot,style=indexgroup,nolist,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{res}
{
    name={resource-awareness},
    description={Foo foo bar}
}

\renewcommand{\glstreeitem}{%
  \parindent0pt\par\hangindent40pt
  \everypar{\parindent50pt\hangindent40pt}}
\renewcommand{\glstreepredesc}{\par
  \glstreeitem\parindent\hangindent}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textnormal{\itshape #1}}
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\parindent0pt\textnormal{\glsgetgrouptitle{#1}}\\}%

\begin{document}

This is not \gls{res}.

\vspace{16cm}

\printnoidxglossary

\end{document}
```

[image]

Btw, I need to use the `indexgroup` style due to some conflicts of other styles with other packages in my document.

Comment: `glstreeitem` and `\glstreepredesc` are new commands I think. So use `\newcommand` there.

Comment: Or is there a missing import?

Comment: @dexteritas Those commands were added to v4.26, so you may have an old version if they're not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\nopagebreak` to prevent a page break. I've made a couple of modifications to your MWE. I added `\nopagebreak` in the separator between the name and description. This prevented the page break you experienced but caused a page break between the header and the first item of the group, which also doesn't look quite right. So I've also adjusted the break after the header.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nopostdot,style=indexgroup,nolist,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{res}
{
    name={resource-awareness},
    description={Foo foo bar}
}

\renewcommand{\glstreeitem}{%
  \parindent0pt\par\hangindent40pt
  \everypar{\parindent50pt\hangindent40pt}}
\renewcommand{\glstreepredesc}{\par\nopagebreak % <-- modified
  \glstreeitem\parindent\hangindent}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textnormal{\itshape #1}}
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\parindent0pt\textnormal{\glsgetgrouptitle{#1}}%
  \par\nopagebreak % <-- modified
}%

\begin{document}

This is not \gls{res}.

\vspace{16cm}

\printnoidxglossary

\end{document}
```

This ends up with a single-paged document:

[image: image of document]

Comment: Thanks, this even fixed the question regarding the letter headers I would have postponed ;-)